# Weird error on a simple ruby program which reverses the words in an input sentence

Tags: ruby

To put things in context, I'm a ruby beginner.

So, I was doing a simple exercise: Create a ruby program which reverses the words in an input sentence.

This is what I did:

```
def reverse_words(sentence)

  reversed_sentence = []
  words = sentence.split(" ")

  i = 0
    while i < words.length
     reversed_sentence = words[i] + reversed_sentence
     i += 1
    end

 return reversed_sentence.join(" ")

end

 # I make a simple test by adding:
puts reverse_words("Hi how are you")
```

When I run the program, it says:

reverse_words_ex.rb:7:in `reverse_words': undefined local variable or method`i' for main:Object (NameError)
    from reverse_words_ex.rb:15:in `'

I don't understand why they say that i is undefined. I would really appreciate some help here.
Thanks

Comment: [Is it supposed to work like this?](https://repl.it/BQ06)

Comment: This line `reversed_sentence = words[i] + reversed_sentence` is wrong, as you sum String and Array. You should think about `<<` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def reverse_words(sentence)
  return sentence.split(" ").reverse.join(" ")
end
```

- `.split(" ")` is splitting your String at each space character, returns an Array
- `.reverse` is reversing the order of the elements in an Array, returns an Array
- `.join(" ")` is joining the elements of an Array with a space character, returns a String